# Authorization immutable (0x4) - Use case

Tags: accounts, flags, authorization

I am trying to imagine a use case scenario where I would use *Authorization immutable (0x4)* flag. The [documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html#flags) states:

> If this is set then none of the authorization flags can be set and the account can never be deleted.

I can think of one scenario, mainly, when the account is an asset issuer and the issuer wants to assure others that the issuing account will never revoke/freeze the assets when other accounts hold them.

What would be the point of ever setting this flag as to render the account essentially frozen and permanently living on the ledger? 
I am particularly interested with the specific real life scenario (other than mentioned above) that would require this flag to be set either as (0x4) or in combination with the other two flags.

Comment: Its more of a trust matter. It guarantees account holders that, the asset their holding will always be valid.

Comment: in fact its a real situation, like it happen with ITC token today. i have 100k of their tokens and they froze my acc today, so what next?)

Answer (score 3):

From a discussion I just had on slack, prompted by your question, it seems the scenario you mention is the sole reason.

> To make guarantees that authorization cannot be revoked - @mikefair

That seems a sufficient reason, even without any other use-case.